# How to allocate budget among employees?

Tags: pm-software

I'm looking for a a way to allocate my budgets among different employees. I need

- an overview of all resources on a timeline.
- allocate budget parts to different workers, e.g. project A has a budget of 2 full-time employees: employee 1 is financed 100 %, employee 2 and 3 50 % each. The other 50 % for 2 and 3 come from a different project.
- All of this must be dynamic, e.g. after 6 months I change plans, define the actual state at this time and allocate the employees to different budgets.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Unfortunately, you are seeking software recommendations. These kinds of questions are off-topic here, because they tend to become obsolete quickly. You can try to ask your question at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought it would be better here because the question is rather specific. Thank you all the same!

Comment: Honestly, I think that PMSE is better place for this kind of specific questions. But [community rules forbid tool recommendations](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are basically looking for resource-management: You want to check if your resources (=employees) are fully occupied, or if you can still assign them to a few other projects. However, this is usually expressed using percent-busy values instead of budgets. [www.project-open.com](http://www.project-open.com) is an open-source PM tool with resource management, so it might work for you (disclaimer: I'm part of the team...).